# How to set adSize?

Tags: android, admob

Using this package  com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize; I can set my adsize like this

```
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
```

But this gms.ads is old one.
Is there any alternative way in which we can achieve the same thing in the new package ie,
    com.google.ads.AdSize;
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you mean 3d banner or any other full screen size banner...

Comment: no normal ads that we are seeing in the bottom of applications.

Comment: can u upload screen short ....if this is 3d banner then you have to make in xml  inside of <com.google.com android:layout_width="200dp" or depends on you what size you want in your app

Comment: same as height of that advertisement

Comment: If this is full schreen size add then you can not change the size of that add because of Advertisement are made Dynamic which are full screen size

Answer (score 8):

You can set custom ads size by this way,

#### Custom Size

```
AdSize customAdSize = new AdSize(250, 250);
PublisherAdView adView = new PublisherAdView(this);
adView.setAdSizes(customAdSize);
```

---

you can set multiple AdSize parameters into *setAdSizes()*

#### Multiple ads sizes

```
adView = new AdView(this);
// adView.setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER, new AdSize(120, 20), new AdSize(250, 250));
```

you can check **[AdSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html)** Documentation

Hope this help you!

Comment: i think you have to help last line of code to set adsize `setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER, new AdSize(120, 20), new AdSize(250, 250));`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/PublisherAdView.html

Comment: i think this publisheradview is also from the old package that is com.gms

Comment: @sunilsunny r u sure to import this packege `import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;` and 
`import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.*;`

Comment: no i don't want to import com.google.android.gms.ads I want to use the  new package com.google.android.ads

Comment: you can first import this 2 package import `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;` or 
`import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;`.  Now you can use adView.setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER, new AdSize(120, 20), new AdSize(250, 250)); to set adsize. reply me

Comment: and i m update last 3 line code check and back on here i m wait

Comment: Is there a way to set this on the setAdListener

Comment: check this 2 link help to you. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android   or https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#android

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom Ad dynamically as following

```
 View adContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.adMobView);
 AdSize customAdSize = new AdSize(150, 150);
        AdView mAdView = new AdView(context);
        mAdView.setAdSize(customAdSize);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(context.getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
        ((RelativeLayout)adContainer).addView(mAdView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

in your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="#000"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adMobView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

For Changing adsize you can change these lines in new Google Ads..

change this line accordingly..

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
```

You can see the details here..

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate

Banner Sizes

Google Mobile Ads supports the following ad formats:

Size (WxH)  Description         Availability            AdSize Constant
320x50          Standard Banner     Phones and Tablets  BANNER
300x250         IAB Medium Rectangle    Tablets             MEDIUM_RECTANGLE
468x60          IAB Full-Size Banner    Tablets             FULL_BANNER
728x90          IAB Leaderboard         Tablets                 LEADERBOARD
See table   Smart Banner            Phones and Tablets  SMART_BANNER

Hope you find the solution here..

Answer (score 1):

you can easily set a custom size like this in XML.

```
ads:adSize="400x400"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Define custom AdSize of 250x250 for PublisherAdView

    AdSize customAdSize = new AdSize(250, 250);

    PublisherAdView adView = new PublisherAdView(this);

    adView.setAdSizes(customAdSize);
```