# I do not see any admob production ads. In react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, admob, react-native-firebase

I connected the admob using the 'react-native-firebase' library.
We plan to apply only interstitial ads.
Currently, we have successfully run interstitial test ads with test id on each platform (ios, android).

However, Admob Dashboard does not call any ads if you apply the "ad unit" id.

Perhaps, does production ads only appear when an app is released? My app has not yet registered with the store and is under development.

Currently, AdMob's mediation and campaign items are untouched. Do I have to write this?

How can we generate a production ad?
I need help!!!

```
controlAdInterstitial = () => {
    // this is production unit id
    const interStialId = Platform.select({
      ios: staticData.admobIds.iosInterstitialId,
      android: staticData.admobIds.androidInterstitialId,
    });
    // run intersitital
    AdInterstitial(interStialId);
    // test id, it's completed
    // AdInterstitial(staticData.admobIds.testInterstitialId);
  };
```

AdIntersitial

```
const AdIntersitial = (id) => {
  const { AdRequest } = firebase.admob;
  const request = new AdRequest();
  const adVert = firebase.admob().interstitial(id);

  adVert.on('onAdLoaded', () => {
    adVert.show();
  });

  adVert.loadAd(request.build());

  adVert.on("onAdOpened", () => {
    console.log('Advert ready to show.');
  });

  const ad = setInterval(() => {
    if (adVert.isLoaded()) {
      adVert.show();
      clearInterval(ad);
    } else {
    }
  }, 2000);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When apps are newly registered with AdMob, it takes some time and a
>   few ads requests to allow inventory to build. Because of this, you may
>   not see live impressions immediately. Once your app starts making more
>   requests, you should see more consistent results. Please note that
>   test ads operate through the same channels as live ads. Being able to
>   return a test ad ensures that your application is communicating
>   properly with our network. Be patience it will work after some days.

As suggested, wait for few hours or a day, if ad id is newly created it will take some time to assign some ads in your ad id.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947588/admob-shows-test-ads-but-not-real-ads)

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation :)
I'll wait patiently.
I wonder if the mediation or campaign in AdMob is showing ads without touching it.
Because I did not touch on these items.