# Unity: I don't receive an AdMob banner or interstitial

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I build my application with Unity everything works fine.
I had messages like:

> Dummy LoadAd

But when I release my build in my device I do not receive any advertising.
I published my application on Play Store and tested on several devices without results.

My unity version is 2018.3.3f1. And the code is blocked in AdMob functions.

This is my code:

```
//request a banner
public void RequestBanner()
  {
    // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-2202385704427937/3307508552";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
#else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

    // Clean up banner ad before creating a new one.
    if (this.bannerView != null)
    {
        this.bannerView.Destroy();
    }

    // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
    this.bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, 
 AdPosition.Top);

    // Register for ad events.
    this.bannerView.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleAdLoaded;
    this.bannerView.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleAdFailedToLoad;
    this.bannerView.OnAdOpening += this.HandleAdOpened;
    this.bannerView.OnAdClosed += this.HandleAdClosed;
    this.bannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication += 
    this.HandleAdLeftApplication;

    // Load a banner ad.
    this.bannerView.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
}


//request a interstitial video
public void RequestInterstitial()
  {
    // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-2202385704427937/1308031170";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
#else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

    // Clean up interstitial ad before creating a new one.
    if (this.interstitial != null)
    {
        this.interstitial.Destroy();
    }

    // Create an interstitial.
    this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

    // Register for ad events.
    this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleInterstitialLoaded;
    this.interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += 
    this.HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
    this.interstitial.OnAdOpening += this.HandleInterstitialOpened;
    this.interstitial.OnAdClosed += this.HandleInterstitialClosed;
    this.interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication += 
    this.HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;

    // Load an interstitial ad.
    this.interstitial.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
}


 //to show video
public void ShowInterstitial()
  {
    if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        this.interstitial.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("Interstitial is not ready yet");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, i dont have 50 points to post this as a comment on your OP. Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947588/admob-shows-test-ads-but-not-real-ads/55199649#55199649), but hey, if everything worked right with your Test Ads, then it is possible that you forgot to add payment details for Live Ads.

Comment: When I tried a older admob plugin test Ads worked fine but real Ads no.

Comment: Now i try a 2018 plugin I receive neither test nor real Ads

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my problem.
I added these lines to android manifest

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.Company.laytonMiniGames"
        android:value="ca-app-pub- 
        2202385704427937~1064488595"/>
```