# IOS - Admob not loading real (rewarded) ads

Tags: ios, swift, admob

When trying to load rewarded ads I get the following error:

`<Google> To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"a 32-character-string" ];`

Loading test ads works, but when trying to show real ads, it says: Request Error: No ad to show.

Apple will not allow my App on the App Store, because the ads don't work.

I have not managed to fix this, since this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947588/admob-shows-test-ads-but-not-real-ads) didn't help.

Adidionally, I have **not used this** in my code: `.addTestDevice()` and my Admob account is way older than 24 hours (it's possibly even many years old).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You usually don't start getting ads until after you make the link between the app store and Admob (`Admob>Apps>YourApp>App Settings>App Store>Link`) which can't be done until it has been in the store for a week or two (In my experience) Apple shouldn't hold your app over non-functioning ads because your UI should not be dependent on Ads. If there are no Ads to show you should handle it gracefully not freeze the screen disable functionality, etc. What if the user is traveling and doesn't have Wifi or cellular service?

Answer (score 0):

depends, If you are using your own device or a simulator you cannot view your own adverts. you have to use a test ad id.

I also suspect that Apple was not holding your app because you did not follow one of their guidelines. You can find them on Apple's [App Review](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/) page. If it is because the ads do not work, try the following:

1. remove the advertisements
2. upload to the app store
3. configure AdMob to use your AppStore id
4. update your app to include the advertisement later

This means there will not be a version of your app that breaks apple's placeholder content rule.

Apple also provides a test service called TestFlight and that may help you.