# Admob ad with 100% screen width and custom(90dp) height

Tags: java, android, admob, height, smartbanner

Im trying to display an admob ad which completely covers the width of screen (like SMART_BANNER), and 90dp constant height.

using this code, i can set the height to 90dp, but how can i make the ad width fill the width?

```
AdSize adSize = new AdSize(deviceSpecificWidth, 90);
```

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#banner_sizes), these are the standard sizes of SMART_BANNER

> Screen width x 32|50|90

can i force the smart banner to only use 90dp height in every device?

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47504617/5773044

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the newly introduced [AdMob Adaptive Banners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive). They don't require adjustments on your side and they utilize all the width available and keeping the aspect ratio (which was a problem before).

Embed them into a FrameLayout like following

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/adFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" />
```